# Managed Metadata group invisible

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

When I go to MMS by going to Central Administration and choose Managed Metadata Services, the group which is used for Managed Navigation is not visible, however when I go through Site Settings and choose Term Store Management I can see the group. why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

Go to Pages library
In the Pages library, on the LIBRARY tab, click Library Settings.
On the Settings page, click Versioning settings.
In the Require Check Out section, for Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited, select No.